# Printing only the first field in a string

Tags: unix, sed, awk, field, cut

I have a date as `12/12/2013 14:32` I want to convert it into only `12/12/2013`.
The string can be `1/1/2013 12:32` or `1/10/2013 23:41` I need only the date part.

Answer (score 72):

You can do this easily with a variety of Unix tools:

```bsh
$ cut -d' ' -f1  <<< "12/12/2013 14:32"
12/12/2013

$ awk '{print $1}' <<< "12/12/2013 14:32"
12/12/2013

$ sed 's/ .*//' <<< "12/12/2013 14:32"
12/12/2013

$ grep -o "^\S\+"  <<< "12/12/2013 14:32"
12/12/2013

$ perl -lane 'print $F[0]' <<< "12/12/2013 14:32"
12/12/2013
```

Comment: `$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv[1].split()[0])" "12/12/2013 14:32"`

Comment: Or to follow the same mold: `$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().split()[0])" <<< "12/12/2013 14:32"`

Answer (score 19):

```
$ echo "12/12/2013 14:32" | awk '{print $1}'
12/12/2013
```

`print $1` --> Prints first column of the supplied string.  `12/12/2013`

`print $2` --> Prints second column of the supplied string.  `14:32`

By default, awk treats the space character as the delimiter.

Answer (score 5):

If your date string is stored in a variable, then you don't need to run an external program like `cut`, `awk` or `sed`, because modern shells like `bash` can perform [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) directly which is more efficient.

For example, in bash:

```
$ s="1/10/2013 23:41"
$ echo "${s% *}"
1/10/2013
```