# How to filter domain in content?

Tags: text

How I can filter domain in content?

For example.... I have some text content, like this:

```
dropwox.com N/A     $ 8.95  1 day ago
lute.info   N/A     $ 8.95  1 week ago
zolpidem4sleep.com  N/A     $ 8.95  1 week ago
youredmedsinfo.com  N/A     $ 8.95  1 week ago
youngsmhs.com   N/A     $ 8.95  1 week ago
jsntcj.com  N/A     $ 8.95  1 week ago
fioricetdirect2k.com    13,133,796      $ 8.95  1 week ago
dapoxetinebuynow.com    N/A     $ 8.95  1 week ago
86620000.com    N/A     $ 8.95  1 week ago
spidvid.com 1,884,910       $ 480.00    1 week ago
titsforall.com  20,318,475      $ 8.95  1 week ago
```

and I just need to filter the domains and see this list like:

```
dropwox.com
lute.info
zolpidem4sleep.com
youredmedsinfo.com
youngsmhs.com
```

Is any tool or online converter for do this work?

Help me

Comment: I don't see how this is related to dns. Also, any preference for operating systems? On linux it's pretty easy.

Comment: sorry it just mistake...

Answer (score 0):

If a shell solution is OK, you can do something like this:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 file | sort | uniq
```

- getting the first word, here using [cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut), but there are [several other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024561/printing-only-the-first-field-in-a-string)
- [sort](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) them so that ...
- [uniq](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq) can filter out the doubles

Comment: Any text editor or some specific one? Look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/520372/how-to-keep-only-the-first-word-in-a-line-using-notepad) for some solutions using Notepad++, probably usable as a start even if you're using another editor, provided that it supports replace based on regex.

Answer (score 0):

That is an old question, but why not answer for coming generations?
If you use MacOS or Linux, there are a bunch of tools:

```
$ cat full_data.txt
dropwox.com N/A     $ 8.95  1 day ago
lute.info   N/A     $ 8.95  1 week ago
zolpidem4sleep.com  N/A     $ 8.95  1 week ago
...
```

You may use any of the following:

sed: removing everything after space:
`$  sed 's/ .*//' full_data.txt > domains.txt`

grep: with regular expression, everything from the beginning (^) until the first space :
`$ grep -o "^\S\+"  full_data.txt > domains.txt`

cut: Pick a first part,  space is a delimeter:
`$ cut -d' ' -f1 full_data.txt > domains.txt`

awk: my beloved awk — pick the first part, space is a delimiter, then printing it:
`$ awk '{print $1}' full_data.txt > domains.txt`

Also, Perl — same, taking first "variable" line by line :
`$ perl -lane 'print $F[0]' full_data.txt > domains.txt`